# user own image folders (security against hacker)

Tags: security, directory

I'm creating a browser based image cloud service and every user will have his own picture folder.

My question is how to make sure, other users or hackers can not access foreign folders.
What is to consider?

Is it e.g. enough to check session-variables?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by just checking the session-variables.

I would create a setup like this:

```
\root
    \userImages
        \user1
            \img1.png
            \img2.png
        \user2
            \img1.png
            \img2.png
    \public
        \index.php
```

I'm assuming you would use PHP or ASP.NET or something similar that uses some type of server like nginx or apahce. You can set the server root to the public folder. This means only your code would have access to the user images.

You can use PHP or whatever language to look at the session information and see if the user is authenticated. If you can, I would recommend encrypting the cookie data with Mycrypt. Once you have checked the authentication, you can get the file with a script and send back header information. Here's a really in depth article that I think would help you if you actually want a how-to. [Protecting Images with  PHP](http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/csshtml/protecting-images-using-php-and-htaccess)

If you are using PHP, [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) handles sessions and protecing images really nicely.